# Drop-down menu of my wordpress website in not working even i created it in menu section of wordpress panel

Tags: wordpress, menu

Hi I created a down menu in my WordPress Website but it is not working. This is my website https://pdfmaze.com.
Below i have Provided some images of my problem.
[image 1: Menus Section in my WordPress admin panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjbFq.png)

[Image 2: My website menus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTI5T.png)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s not about programming

Answer (score 0):

After investigating, it looks like you are using this WordPress theme: https://exthem.es/item/apkdone-themes-premium/ (Apkdone). From their own Live demo, it does **not** look like this theme supports dropdown menus. However, if you feel comfortable you can code this feature yourself. It would also be helpful to know what version of WordPress this theme is installed on.

In your header.php file, you should have some code that looks similar to this:

```
wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'theme_location' => 'primary',
        'depth' => 3 // This is the depth of dropdown menus
        'container'  => ''
    )
);
```

The depth attribute defines how deep you can go with your dropdown menus, I have not read the code but from what I have seen it seems, for this theme, this attribute is null/0.

This video might be able to help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TmmLRv9yY0M

Here are the official WordPress developer docs on navbar menus: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/

I hope this helps!